# TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a blog where i get the information from Firestore database. But I keep getting this error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`.
[image]

Here is my HTML code:
[image]

Here is my JavaScript code:
[image]

Here is the Firestore Database:
[image]

Comment: Please paste minimal code into the question, otherwise, it's quite hard to read

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4284627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error you are getting isn't related to Firebase at all but rather to `document.querySelector` on line 16. The function expects a valid CSS selector to be passed, so if you want to find element by id you should prepend selector with "#". In your case there is also a typo so at the end it should look like this to work:

```js
let postCollection = document.querySelector('#post-collection');
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Glad to know that, feel free to upvote and mark this answer as correct if it helped. By the way, usually, error stack traces are there to help you pinpoint the problem, sometimes it's worthwhile to look through them :)